# Google Maps Api v2 Android Error loading map on Play Store

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with google maps API but when i upload my APK to Play Store my map doesn't load, when i run my app directly on my device it works perfect. When i generate my Signet APK and test it on my device (without Play Store, just sending my APK to my device and installing it manually) it works perfect, but if i publish the exactly same APK to Play Store it isnt visible after i downloaod it.

my app gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "development.senseit.com.mapasinteca"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 102
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\jsalazar\\Desktop\\Certificados\\Android\\mapasInteca.jks')
            storePassword '****'
            keyAlias 'mapasinteca'
            keyPassword '****'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

My google API key is correct.
I have 2 finger print certificate added to google console, one for debug and one for release (i already trying removing the debug one).

Comment: I believe you need to add your SHA5 code

Comment: could you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem adding one SHA-1 that i was missing, it was on Google Play Console (number 1 on image) i was only adding number 2

[image: Problem Solved]